# Overriding material-ui max column count by transposing the grid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a matrix of cards :

https://codesandbox.io/s/u93zn

The problem is, the number of columns in our use case is always going to be higher than rows
( and higher than the maximum that grid can create = 12 ). We can have unlimited stations but only 10 lines.

So I'm thinking about transposing the grid . I've tried direction="column" but that always creates just one column.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So are you looking for a horizontally scrolling, potentially infinite list?

Comment: Sorry , no . I'm thinking about vertically scrolling...basically my example , but transposing rows to columns.

Answer (score 0):

So in order to prevent wrapping, on the container element:

'.MuiGrid-container'

if you swap out the 'flex-wrap:wrap' for 'flex-wrap: nowrap' it will continue past 100% width

Comment: this is not exactly what I'm after. Currently for every "line" in const data I'm creating a row of N cards based on number of "stations" for each "line". I'd like to create a column of N cards based on number of "stations" for each line. Right now I've got ( when screen is maximised ) 10 rows of data with 12 columns , want to transpose it to 10 columns of data with 12 rows. Thanks for the effort :)